# Snowflake connectivity issue from Power BI/Tableau

Tags: powerbi, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tableau-desktop

maybe a newbie question, but it's the first time I'm trying to connect to Snowflake from a BI tool.
I created a 30 trial account on Snowflake (not related to any organization) and trying to connect from both Power BI and Tableau (Desktop), but I receive a login error after inserting the credentials.
From Power BI:

[Power BI error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAZRh.png)

*Details: "ODBC: ERROR [HY000] [Microsoft][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL https://app.snowflake.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=5fc2d087-7791-4094-85ae-a10f6712b1f2&request_guid=96ad6779-8c15-4e2d-8b19-7878d60e314d&warehouse=COMPUTE_WH failed: HTTP error (http error) - code=405.*

From Tableau:

[Tableau error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljkX2.png)

*An error occurred while communicating with Snowflake
Invalid username or password.
Error Code: 2438FAD7
[Snowflake][Snowflake] (4)
REST request for URL https://app.snowflake.com:443/session/v1/login-request?requestId=dec8ccd1-0d44-4f70-ba3c-a7da258b3cb1&request_guid=7da8e38a-926e-46af-9933-241556e11a05 failed: HTTP error (http error) - code=405.
*

I am using app.snowflake.com as the server, and my username and passwords as the credentials.
The user is has an ACCOUNTADMIN role.
I've tried to google the error but without luck.
Does someone has any clue what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating the ODBC or any connection, as the server include the whole URL as example below.

```
qf3XX52.europe-west4.gcp.snowflakecomputing.com
```

Answer (score 0):

The url used is incorrect since app.snowflake.com is the URL for Snowsight application, it is not the entry point for any 3rd party application to Snowflake.

The correct URL for PowerBI would be in the following format:
"account-identifier".snowflakecomputing.com or if using the regionless format, then it would be : "org-name"-"acct-name".snowflakecomputing.com

Account identifier information is here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-account-identifier.html#account-identifier-formats-by-cloud-platform-and-region